# Where am I leaking memory here? Used Instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, instruments

Instruments is saying there is a memory leak in this code:

```
- (void)layoutImageMaskViewForImageAtPath:(NSString *)path withFillColor:(UIColor *)color indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [self layoutImageMaskViewForImage:image withFillColor:color indexPath:indexPath];
}

UIColor *anIconFillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.70 alpha:1.0];
NSIndexPath *anIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSString *aPlaceholderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"path" ofType:@"png"];
[self layoutImageMaskViewForImage:anImage withFillColor:anIconFillColor indexPath:anIndexPath];
```

and

```
NSDictionary *anAssignedData = [aReservationData objectForKey:kAssignedSectionKey];
NSMutableArray *anEmployeeTaskQueueList = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *anAssignedReservationData = [anAssignedData objectForKey:kEmployeesIdentifier];

for (NSDictionary *aJobQueueData in anAssignedReservationData) {
    EmployeeReservationQueue *anAssignedTaskQueue = [[EmployeeReservationQueue alloc] initWithServerDictionary:aJobQueueData];

    if (anAssignedTaskQueue.rows.count == 0) {
        ReservationTrack *aTrack = [[ReservationTrack alloc] init];
        aTrack.rowSortOrder = 0;
        aTrack.reservations = [NSArray array];
        anAssignedTaskQueue.rows = [NSArray arrayWithObject:aTrack];
        [aTrack release];
    }

    [anEmployeeTaskQueueList addObject:anAssignedTaskQueue];
    [anAssignedTaskQueue release];
}
```

Comment: Try running the static analyzer in Xcode (command + shift + B).

Comment: Nothing found by static analyzer.

Comment: I don't see any leaks here, but if instruments says so, it is not necessary that this particular code snippet is the culprit. It might be somewhere else, which is just related to this part of the code

Comment: Which object? That's what Instruments usually points to, not code.

And like aqs said, it could be an object that owns this one that is being leaked.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example leaks `track`.  Your last line is releasing `aTrack` instead.

Comment: No, I am releasing `track`, I just typed it wrong in this question.

Answer (score 1):

In second case here:

```
[aTrack release];
```

What is `aTrack`? May be you mean `[track release];`?

In first case probably that you pass to function non-autoreleased parameters or may be you are not releasing them after calling that method. Just post code where you call for that method and I will check.

Comment: In first case, none of parameters passed are init/alloc/released.  `NSString`, `UIColor` and `NSIndexPath` are not alloc/init so they are never released.

Comment: No, I am releasing `track`, I just typed it wrong in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Gold memory-management rule in Objective-C :
Each 'init', 'copy','mutableCopy','retain' must call then 'release' or 'autorelease'.

Comment: No, I am releasing `track`, I just typed it wrong in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments reports that your app is leaking a `ReservationTrack` object.  By default it shows where the leaked object was allocated, which is the code you posted.  The code you posted doesn't leak a `ReservationTrack`.  It stores it in an `EmployeeReservationQueue` which is stored in an `NSMutableArray`.  One possibility is that you later access the `ReservationTrack` object, send it `retain`, and don't send it `release` or `autorelease`.  Another possibility is that you leak the `EmployeeReservationQueue` or the `NSMutableArray`.

If you use the simulator, you can see the full retain/release history of most objects.  When a leaked object shows up, mouse over the address of the object and click the right arrow that appears next to the address.  Instruments will show you every `malloc`, `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` event for that object.  If you choose View > Extended Detail from the menu bar, you can click on any of those events and see the stack trace of the event.  This should help you track down the unbalanced `retain`.